# PHP - calculating the number of weeks between two dates

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to calculate the number of weeks between two dates. The code below has a result of 3 weeks. However, it is really 4 weeks. Why is it calculating incorrectly and what is the solution?

I'm curious to know why this specific code isn't working but would also like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

I'm running PHP version 7.2. Below is the code I'm using:

```
$HowManyWeeks = date( 'W', strtotime( 2019-04-21 23:59:00 ) ) - date( 'W', strtotime( 2019-03-25 00:00:00 ) );
```

The value of $HowManyWeeks should be 4 but it is displaying as 3.

Also, when I try that code at https://phpfiddle.org/ it gives an error of:

```
Line : 2 -- syntax error, unexpected '23' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ')'
```

But it displays '3' without any error when running it on my server.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dates you pass to [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) need to be enclosed in quotes. And the correct answer is indeed 3, as there are 3 weeks, 6 days, 23 hours and 59 minutes between the two times. Try this:

```
$HowManyWeeks = date( 'W', strtotime( '2019-04-21 23:59:00' ) ) - date( 'W', strtotime( '2019-03-25 00:00:00' ) );
echo $HowManyWeeks;
```

As has been pointed out, this will only work when the weeks are in the same year. It's easier to use `DateTime` objects as in @MiroslavGlamuzina answer or you can simply divide the `strtotime` difference by 604800 (seconds in a week); you can then take the `floor` or `ceil` if required to convert to an integer value:

```
$HowManyWeeks = (strtotime( '2019-04-21 23:59:00' ) - strtotime( '2019-03-25 00:00:00' )) / 604800;
echo $HowManyWeeks;
```

Output:

```
3.9939484126984
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uqJqh)

Comment: This code will only work for dates within a given year. For example; Jan 1 2018 and Jan 9 2017 will only result in a one week difference.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina you are absolutely correct. I've updated with something more robust. But +1 to you...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DateTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to achieve this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2017-04-30');
$date2 = new DateTime('2019-04-30');
// I have left the remainer. You may need to round up/down. 
$differenceInWeeks = $date1->diff($date2)->days / 7;
print_r($differenceInWeeks);
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

> The value of $HowManyWeeks should be 4

Why? please note in php a week is [begin with Monday](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), and I count in the calendar, it's exactly 3.

If you need 4 (Sunday as the first day of week), check the day of week

```
$time1 = strtotime('2019-04-21 23:59:00');
$week1 = idate('W', $time1);
if(idate('w', $time1) == 0) # Sunday, next week
    $week1++;
...
```